# Django - Method not Allowed (POST) after send data via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Error: `Method Not Allowed (POST): / 405` occurs when submitting form via AJAX with POST method. Ultimately this should take all submitted values (first_name, last_name, phone, email) and save them respectively to proper Models with Foreign Key. I'm currently using class-based views and in def post  I have to save object with simple validation but for few hours I wonder how to do it.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AddressView.as_view()),
    path('add/', views.AddressPost.as_view()),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.AddressDelete.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class AddressView(generic.ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'address_book/main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddressView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'people_list': Person.objects.all(),
            'phones_list': Phone.objects.order_by('person_id'),
            'email_list': Email.objects.all(),
        })
        return context


class AddressDelete(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Person.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        self.get_object(pk).delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)


class AddressPost(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

**add_contact.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
        var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        $("#addContactForm").submit(function(event){
              var next_id = parseInt($("#addressTab tbody tr:last-child td:first-child").html())+1;
              var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
              var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
              var phone = $("#phone").val();
              var email = $("#email").val();
              if (first_name != "" && last_name != ""){
                  var markup = "<tr><td id='person-id'>" + next_id + "</td><td id='person-first_name'>"
                   + first_name + "</td><td id='person-last_name'>" + last_name + "</td><td id='person-phone'>"
                                + phone + "</td><td id='person-email'>" + email + "</td><td id='person-delete'></td></tr>";

                   $.ajax({
                        url: "add/",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $("#addContactForm").serialize(),
                        contentType:'application/json',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        error: function(result){
                             M.toast({html: 'Kontakt niepoprawnie dodany', classes: 'red rounded', displayLength:3000})
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                             $("#addressTab tbody").append(markup);
                             $("form").trigger('reset');
                             M.toast({html: 'Kontakt poprawnie dodany', classes: 'green rounded', displayLength:3000})
                        }
                    )};

              }else{
                M.toast({html: 'Proszę wpisać imię i nazwisko dla nowego kontaktu.', classes: 'red rounded', displayLength:3000})
              }
            return false;
        });
});
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def phones(self):
        return list(Phone.objects.filter(person=self).values_list('phone', flat=True))

    @property
    def emails(self):
        return list(Email.objects.filter(person=self).values_list('email', flat=True))


class Phone(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Judging by the error, the POST went to the `/` url instead of `/add` and your view which handles `/` url does not support POST.

Comment: But how its possible that POST went to ```/``` url when in ajax url I wrote 'add/'. Also I tried with 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/add' and the same result appears.